# How to convert a windows forms application into an ActiveX control?

Tags: .net, winforms, browser, activex

I have a windows forms application and I need to convert it into an ActiveX application so that it can be called from the browser.

I have tried various tutorials on the internet, but none of them are working. I cannot get the form to load in the browser. I have also tried changing the security settings in IE to see if it'll make a difference, but it did not.

Any ideas?

Comment: this are kind of job sometimes manager asks to save moneys...

Comment: You need a UserControl, toplevel windows like Form are not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed it to UserControl and now the form is loading in the browser. But, i have a problem here. I have a background worker that performs some validations and updates the UI based on it. Are there any changes to its implementation in UserControl or is it similar to Windows Forms? Because everything is fine in the windows app.